# What does the CDKToolkit's BootstrapVersion SSM parameter represent?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-ssm

I am using AWS CDK toolkit to create our infrasture. I created helloworld-stack.ts file and when I do cdk synth then this process creates HelloWorldStack.template.json file.
In this file we have some auto generated elements. Like this one.
Now, I am not able to understand, how bootstraping pushes this "/cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version" to SSM store and why this key always has value 14.

Can someone help me to understand this behaviour?

```
 "Parameters": {
  "BootstrapVersion": {
   "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>",
   "Default": "/cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version",
   "Description": "Version of the CDK Bootstrap resources in this environment, automatically retrieved from SSM Parameter Store. [cdk:skip]"
  }
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading AWS offical doc regarding bootstrapping, I got the answer.

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html
```

In this doc, they mentioned it this is their template version.

[image]